# Failed to minify the code from this file:

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have looked at similar questions to this, but i've tried going through the answers and banging my head against the wall trying to resolve the issue.

I'm using `create-react-app`.

It works fine on developement build i.e `npm start`

But fails on production i.e `npm run build`

> Creating an optimized production build...
>   
> Failed to compile.
>   
>   
> Failed to minify the code from this file:
>   
> ./src/components/Indecision.js

Here is the code:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import AddOptions from './AddOptions';
import Options from './options';
import Header from './Header';
import Action from './Action';
import OptionModal from './optionModal'
import '../styles/styles.scss';
import '../styles/styles.css';

class Indecision extends Component {

    state = {
        options: [],
        selectedOption: undefined
    }

    handleClearSelected = () => {
        this.setState(() => ({ selectedOption: undefined }))
    }

    handleDeleteOptions = () => {
        this.setState(() => ({ options: [] }))
    }

    handleDeleteOption = (optionToRemove) => {
        this.setState((prevState) => ({
            options: prevState.options.filter((option) => optionToRemove !== option)
        }))
    }

    handlePick = () => {
        const randomNum = Math.floor(Math.random() * this.state.options.length)
        const option = this.state.options[randomNum]
        this.setState(() => ({ selectedOption: option }))
    }

    handleAddOption = (option) => {
        if (!option) {
            return 'Enter valid value to add item'
        } else if (this.state.options.indexOf(option) > -1) {
            return 'This option already exists'
        }
        this.setState((prevState) => ({ options: prevState.options.concat([option]) }))
    }

    componentDidMount() {
        try {
            const json = localStorage.getItem('options')
            const options = JSON.parse(json)
            if (options) {
                this.setState(() => ({ options }))
            }
        } catch (error) {

        }
    }

    componentDidUpdate(prevProps, prevState) {
        if (prevState.options.length !== this.state.options.length) {
            const json = JSON.stringify(this.state.options)
            localStorage.setItem('options', json)
        }
    }

    render() {
        const title = 'Indecision'
        const subtitle = 'Put your life in the hands of the Machine'

        return (
            <div className="App" >
                <Header title={title} subtitle={subtitle} />
                <div className="container">
                    <Action hasOptions={this.state.options.length > 0}
                            handlePick={this.handlePick}
                    />
                    <div className='widget'>
                        <Options
                                options={this.state.options}
                                handleDeleteOptions={this.handleDeleteOptions}
                                handleDeleteOption={this.handleDeleteOption}
                        />
                        <AddOptions
                                handleAddOption={this.handleAddOption}
                        />
                    </div>
                </div>
                <OptionModal
                        selectedOption={this.state.selectedOption}
                        handleClearSelected={this.handleClearSelected}
                />
            </div>
        );
    }
}

export default Indecision
```